# Batch file rename script swapping substrings in filename?

Tags: python, shell, batch-file

I have a group of files named like **title_december_word1_word2.png** and want to iterate through the directory and swap `word1` and `word2` within each file.

i.e. go from `"button_december_state_pressed.png" -> "button_december_pressed_state.png"`

Any suggestion on how I might accomplish this?

Most batch programs I've found for OS X can't specify a char to break down words and I was hoping someone could help me with a quick script to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rename` util. It uses `sed` syntax to replace names

```
rename 's/old-name/new-name/' files
```

Command will look something like this

```
 rename 's/$(.*december_)(.*)_(.*)(.png)^/\1\3_\2\4/' *.png
```

Comment: I would recommend using backreferences `$1`, `$2`... instead of `\1`, `\2`, although the latter works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Here's a batch code to  do it.
Copy this code an put it in a file "Swap.bat"

```
@ECHO OFF

for %%a in (*.png) do (
     for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=_" %%b in ('echo %%~na') do (
        echo ren "%%a" "%%b_%%c_%%e_%%d%%~xa"))
Pause
```

I put an `echo` before the `ren` that you can test the code without problem.
If the output is OK remove the `echo`

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: ^ that'd be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Its not pretty but I think it does what you want if all your files are in the same folder

```
import os

files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

[os.rename(i,
    '_'.join([i.split('_')[0],
        i.split('_')[1],
        i.split('_')[3][:-4],
        i.split('_')[2]+
        '.png'])) for i in files if len(i.split('_')) == 4 and i[-3:] == 'png']
```

or you can use format and/or a for loop?

```
for fileName in files:
    if fileName[-4:] == '.png':
        words = fileName[:-4].split('_')
        os.rename(fileName,
            '{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}.png'.format(words[0],
                words[1],
                words[3],
                words[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

try the small [rename-regex](https://github.com/nicjansma/rename-regex/downloads) (no installation):

```
rr *_*_*_*.png "(.*)_(\w+)_(\w+).png" "$1_$3_$2.png"
```